# Nth Child for ul li a links

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to get a special styling for `ul` `li` `a` elements. Here's the code:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like the second link (Two) to have a different styling (`color`) than the other two (One and Three).

This is what I've been trying, but it does not seem to work:

`#menu li a:nth-child(even) {color:red;}`

Any tips for getting this to work? Here is a fiddle all set up:

http://jsfiddle.net/DSkfH/

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:nth-child()` selects elements from amongst their siblings, in this case the `a` elements have no siblings, so you'll need to employ the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class to the `li` instead:

```
#menu li:nth-child(even) a {color:red;}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DSkfH/1/).

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to respond, it worked perfectly and thank you for explaining as well:)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
#menu li:nth-child(even) a {color:red;}
```

if you want the color on the li as well you'll need also

```
#menu li:nth-child(even) {color:red;}
```

You cant just have the `li` selector because the colour property is not inherited by the `a` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/DSkfH/3/

Comment: Thanks so much, I just wanted it on the `a` so the first example worked perfectly