# Applying CSS classes to plugin-generated elements of the same tag?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

Basically, I have a plugin that generates a HTML menu made up of one `<ul>` tag and several `<li>` tags. I want to apply different background colors to each menu item, but I am unable to add these CSS classes to each list item due to them being programmatically generated, therefore directly inaccessible. Is there a way to apply different classes to multiple child elements of the same tag? Without accessing the plugin files, in my case.

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931492/nth-child-for-ul-li-a-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use the [nth-of-type(n)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector to target different `<li>` elements without adding classes to the generated code.

```css
body {font-size: 22px}

ul li:nth-of-type(1){background:red}
ul li:nth-of-type(2){background:blue}
ul li:nth-of-type(3){background:green}
ul li:nth-of-type(4){background:yellow}
ul li:nth-of-type(5){background:orange}
ul li:nth-of-type(6){background:purple}
ul li:nth-of-type(7){background:cyan}
ul li:nth-of-type(8){background:brown}
ul li:nth-of-type(9){background:pink}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Watermelon</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cheese</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
  <li>Jam</li>
  <li>Sugar</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use other elements on the page to make sure the changes are only applied to the element you want to affect.

example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 22px
}

.foo ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red
}

.foo ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: blue
}

.foo ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green
}

.foo ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">

  <h1> First List (not modified)</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Watermelon</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="foo">

  <h1> Second List (modified)</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Watermelon</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="bar">

  <h1> Third List (not modified)</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Watermelon</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!